# Checking a camera or image for pixel size

Tags: java, android, android-camera

So I was following [this](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/03/15/crop-an-image-in-android/) tutorial and it says on the tutorial that it assumes the image is 300px x 300px.  How do I figure out how large my image is in terms of px when I have just gotten the image from the camera on the phone (not through an instance if that matters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example referenced in the question is opening an existing `Bitmap` image from the application's resources like this:

```
Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.image);
```

## How To Get Android Image Bitmap Size

You can determine the width and height of this or any `Bitmap` with [getWidth()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getWidth%28%29) and [getHeight()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getHeight%28%29) as below:

```
int width = bitmapOrg.getWidth();
int height = bitmapOrg.getHeight();
```

The complete documentation for `Bitmap` is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html).

---

Regarding the 300x300 pixel size, the example is forcing those sizes and creating a new `Bitmap` with the hardcoded values, as below:

```
int targetWidth = 300;
int targetHeight = 300;
Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth, targetHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```